# closed-form solution to $\int_0^\infty x^a\exp(-bx)\left(\frac{1}{\text{erfc}(c\sqrt{x})}\right)^{2a}$

Tags: calculus, integration, error-function

This integral comes up in a problem in Statistics involving power laws. [Here](https://github.com/maxbiostat/bayesian_power_law/blob/master/notes/power_law_Bayesian.pdf) are some notes if anyone is interested. The integral in question would be related to equation (7) therein.

I would like to compute 
$$
\int_0^\infty x^a\exp(-bx)\left(\frac{1}{\text{erfc}(c\sqrt{x})}\right)^{2a} dx,
$$
where $b > 0$, $a >0$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and erfc is the [complementary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Complementary_error_function).

This looks hopeless. Anything I could try to squeeze out a closed-form solution?